# Quadrant 3 positions in a quadrant 4 imageview

Tags: android, maps, indoor-positioning-system

I'm putting together a demo of indoor positioning technology for an Android device.  The problem is that I am getting quadrant 3 positions from the system I'm using, where 0,0 origin is in the upper right.  The map is placed in an imageview that has the origin in the upper left (quadrant 4).

[image: Points map]

Naturally, when I try to put another image on top to move around according to the position I am getting, it is backwards on the X-axis.  What is the best way to display the right coordinates?  Can I transform the points as I get them, or is there a way to somehow flip the imageview so that the origin is in the upper right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to transform the coordinates yourself. It is not complex - mapping the values from one to the other, in general. If the image has a width of "Wo" and you have Vo (View Origin) and Mo (Map Origin) then an x coordinate from the Map is Mx and is transformed as Vx = Mx + Wo. (Mx are map x coordinates that have negative values, no greater than Wo and no less than 0). To transform from the view to the map, do the opposite: Mx = Vx - Wo. (The Vx x-coordinates will not have values less than 0, and at its greatest width, it should result in a "0" on the map.)

That is not CPU intensive, so it should be fast.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!